# Is it possbile to have multiple instances of the service with the same clientId in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, nms

I've created a test with two consumers each using its own connection. I need to be sure that only one of them receives the message.

These consumers use the same clientId and name.

Whenever I set clientId for the second consumer I get the following exception:

> **Apache.NMS.InvalidClientIDException**: Broker: localhost - Client: *TwoDurableConsumers_SameConsumerNameAndCientId_OnlyOneReceivesMessageb9182d05-b1b4-46b0-afb0-074b52ad7071* already connected from tcp://0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58629
>       at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.CheckConnected() in c:\dev\NMS.ActiveMQ\src\main\csharp\Connection.cs:line 1041

`TwoDurableConsumers_SameConsumerNameAndCientId_OnlyOneReceivesMessageb9182d05-b1b4-46b0-afb0-074b52ad7071` is both `clientId` and `durable subscriber name`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two clients with the same client ID which is what the error is telling you.  The client ID is a unique identifier which works to prevent exactly what you are trying to do, so the answer is don't do that.

Comment: But what is the way to have multiple instances subscribing to the same topic as a single consumer from the point of view of ActiveMQ? In the sense that only one of the instance should receive a message?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a Queue

Comment: [Virtual Topics !](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html)